# How to get FeatureClass or FeatureLayer from FeatureClassID?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, geometric-network, utility-network

I did a network analysis with `ITraceFlowSolverGEN` and the method `FindFlowElements()`. Then I did a queryId's with `INetElements` which returns the `FeatureClassId` and `OID`. 
Now I want to get the `FeatureClass` Or `FeatureLayer` or anything that I can get the shape of the object.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Well, Yes, but I found another way to do that because I Did not know how to create INetworkAnalysisExt. Thanks anyway Farid.

Comment: If you had asked I would tell you how to get a handle of INetworkAnalysisExt! I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you Farid , I had to do it very fast ...but I would appreciate if you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the snippet:

```
IApplication app = ...
UID uidUtilNet = new UIDClass() { Value = "esriEditorExt.UtilityNetworkAnalysisExt" };
var m_utilNetExt = app.FindExtensionByCLSID(uidUtilNet) as IUtilityNetworkAnalysisExt;
nax = m_utilNetExt as INetworkAnalysisExt;

for (int i = 0; i < nax.FeatureLayerCount; i++)
{
    IFeatureLayer featureLayer = nax.get_FeatureLayer(i);
    if (featureLayer == null)
    {
        logger.log.Info("null feature layer,i=" + i.ToString());
        continue;
    }
    IFeatureClass featClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
    if (featClass.FeatureClassID == classID)
    {
        if (featClass.HasOID)
            var feat = featClass.GetFeature(objID);
            //do something with  feat.Shape
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.

`

```
IEnumLayer oLayers = ClsShare.GMapDocument.Map[0].get_Layers(null, true);

    ILayer[] ListOfLayers = new ILayer[200];
                    IFeatureLayer Ifl;
                    int FeatureClassId;
    while ((oLayer = oLayers.Next()) != null)
                    {
                      var Type = oLayer.Valid;
                        if (Type)
                        {
                            Ifl = oLayer as IFeatureLayer;
                            FeatureClassId = Ifl.FeatureClass.FeatureClassID;
                            ListOfLayers[FeatureClassId] = oLayer;
                        }
                        else { continue; }
                    }
```

So I have all the layers in an array and dont need to loop through the layers for every query i make.

Comment: This is similar to my answer, except that you have looped through map layers instead of network analysis layers. This should work too, although one problem may occur. what if your network layer is not present in your map! e.g. a user has removed a layer that is part of a geometric network from the map. Then you can not find the corresponding layer.

Comment: well...Removing the layers is not an option in my web application.

Comment: I suppose you are using the old web adf api which is deprecated! @Arvin, consider marking the correct answer per [tour](http://www.gis.stackexchange.com)